# how to construct a (2nd order) ODE that will be satisfied by a provided fundamental set?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If given a couple of functions and asked to construct an ODE of the form $y'' + q(x)y' + r(x)y = 0$ admitting of that couple as a fundamental set, once we've established that the couple could be a fundamental set (e.g. by showing that the Wronskian is never zero on the interval of interest), where do we go from there?

e.g. given $v_1 = x^2$ and $v_2 = xe^x$, I know the Wronskian is non-zero for $x>0$, but I don't have a clue how to find a 2nd order DE that would be satisfied by this set... I tried playing around with the derivatives, but it is not systematic (like other questions where the solutions given are to 2nd order constant-coefficient cases) and I'm not seeing anything.

Any insight would be appreciated. Best, Rax

Comment: since $v_1$ and $v_2$ is the solution of the equation? Can I just use $v_1'' + q v_1'+v_1 r=0$ and $v_2'' + q v_2'+v_2 r=0$ to find out q and r?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say, you have a pair of fundamental solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$. They should satisfy the ODE you're looking for
\begin{align}
y_1'' + qy_1' + ry_1 &= 0 \tag 1 \\
y_2'' + qy_2' + ry_2 &= 0 \tag 2
\end{align}
Now, multiple $(1)$ to $y_2$ and $(2)$ to $y_1$ and subtract one from another
$$
q(y_2y_1' - y_1 y_2') = y_1 y_2'' - y_2 y_1'' \implies q = \frac {y_1 y_2'' - y_2 y_1''}{y_2y_1' - y_1 y_2'}
$$
This time, multiply $(1)$ to $y_1'$ and $(2)$ to $y_2'$, so
$$
r(y_1 y_2' - y_2 y_1') = y_1' y_2'' - y_2' y_1'' \implies r = \frac {y_1' y_2'' - y_2' y_1''}{y_1 y_2' - y_2 y_1'}
$$
Their existence is guaranteed by the non zero Wronskian.

Comment: Clear, concise & easy to follow. Thank you!